# Can't get IPython to run Python 2.7 instead of 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

I'm on Arch Linux trying to make IPython run Python 2.7 instead of Python 3.5.
I already edited /usr/bin/ipython, that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# This script was automatically generated by setup.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from IPython import start_ipython
    start_ipython()
```

and on the first line I substituted

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

for

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
```

But after that when I tried to run IPython I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 4, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
ImportError: No module named IPython
```

I'd like to know what do I have to do to be able to run Python2.7 when I type ipython and run Python3 when I type ipython3

Comment: Did you install the ipython package with `pip3`?

Comment: No, I installed ipython with the Arch Linux package manager 'pacman'

Comment: Sure, but should probably be using `pip` instead to manage your Python related packages.

Comment: Ok,thanks for the advice! So how do I install IPython with pip and get it to run Python 2.7 instead of 3.5?

Comment: `python2 -m IPython` loads a Python2 IPython for me... I don't what what your `/usr/bin/python` version is, though, so hard to say.

Comment: It didn't work for me... I'm going to uninstall ipython and install it again using pip this time.Thanks for your help!